# Dot product of symbolic vector

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to take the dot product of a symbolic vector and another vector. I did the following:

```
>> rac = sym('rac',[3 1])

  rac =

    rac1
    rac2
    rac3

>> i = [1;0;0]

  i =

    1
    0
    0

>> dot(rac,i)

  ans =

    conj(rac1)
```

However my desired outcome is `rac1`. Why is it not behaving like I want it to? And how do I achieve this output?

Comment: If `rac1` is real, `conj(rac1) == rac1`, hence MATLAB is entirely correct, albeit a bit enthusiastic in showing you results in the complex plane, whereas you only require results on the real axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that your symbolic vector is [real](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#inputarg_set):

```
rac = sym('rac', [3 1], 'real');
dot(rac, [1; 0; 0])

ans =

rac1
```